# Improve code that converts an Array using Ruby 'map' and 'splat'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to improve *code* below, maybe using some Ruby on Rails method.

I have an Array `["one", "two", "three"]` for which I make

```
# From `Symbol`s to `String`s
array = [:one, :two, :three].map {|k| k.to_s}
# => ["one", "two", "three"]
```

and then (the `attr_accessible` method used below is just a *sample* method and only serves to give an idea of what I do; in production I use the "splat" array in a my custom method)

```
attr_accessible *array
# => attr_accessible "one", "two", "three"
```

Is there a better way to make the above? If so, how can I "convert" the `["one", "two", "three"]` array in an "elegant" way?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You have symbols and strings mixed up.  Should your initial code block not contain strings?

Comment: @Gazler - My first block converts array element from `Symbol`s to `String`s. What do you mean exactly with "Should your initial code block not contain strings?"?

Comment: You have an array of symbols, which you convert to strings, but doesn't attr_accessible expect symbols?

Comment: @Gazler - Yes, you are right. However, the `attr_accessible` is just an sample method; I use the "splat" array in a my custom method.

Comment: @Backo, can you please be more specific in what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain Ruby you can do

```
array = [:one, :two, :three].map(&:to_s)
```

With the map_by_method gem you can do:

```
array = [:one, :two, :three].map_by_to_s
```

If you implement your custom method like this:

```
def foo(*args)
  converted_args = args.flatten.map(&:to_s)
end
```

You can call it like

```
 foo "one", "two", "three"
 foo :one, :two, :three

 args = [:one, :two, :three]
 foo *args
 foo args # see flatten above
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear to me. I can't make out whether you want to convert an array of strings to an array of symbols, or if you want to convert an array of symbols to an array of strings? Or maybe you're looking for a better solution than using splat. In any case ...

To convert strings to symbols, use to_sym.

```
["one", "two", "three"].map(&:to_sym)
```

To convert symbols to strings, use to_s (as @Mr.Ronald's answer shows)

```
[:one, :two, :three].map(&:to_s)
```